# Enum with struct as values?

Tags: c, enums

So I'm pretty new to C (and to programming in general), I'd like to use a struct as the values for an enum

```
typedef struct {
  int x;
  int y;
} point;

// here's what I'd like to do
enum directions {
  UP = point {0, 1},
  DOWN = point {0, -1},
  LEFT = point {-1, 0},
  RIGHT = point {1, 0}
};
```

So that afterwards I could use the enum to perform coordinate transformations

If you understand what I'm trying to achieve could you please explain why this doesn't work and/or what would be the correct way to do it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`enum` is only used for translating "magic numbers" into something textual and meaningful. They can only be used for integers.

Your example is something more complex than that. It would seem that what you are really looking for is a struct, containing 4 different `point` members. Possibly `const` qualified. Example:

```
typedef struct {
  int x;
  int y;
} point;

typedef struct {
  point UP;
  point DOWN;
  point LEFT;
  point RIGHT;
} directions; 

...

{
  const directions dir = 
  {
    .UP    = (point) {0, 1},
    .DOWN  = (point) {0, -1},
    .LEFT  = (point) {-1, 0},
    .RIGHT = (point) {1, 0}
  };
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No, an enumeration is a collection of integral constants only. One way to approximate what you want (constant expressions of a point type) is with the preprocessor and compound literals:

```
#define UP    (point){0, 1}
#define DOWN  (point){0, -1}
#define LEFT  (point){-1, 0}
#define RIGHT (point){1, 0}
```

This will work only if you aren't chained to obsolete versions of C for some silly reason, since compound literals were added in C99.

Comment: Note that the term "ANSI C" has long been obsolete and at times confusing these days.

Comment: @P.P. - It was mostly a jab at people who claim they can't use modern C for whatever reason

Comment: Reason are at times not silly, people are stuck with compilers/version, because a change might affect millions _life_ cheers ;)

Comment: @P0W - At times. But the OP is new to C by their own admission. The only reason they can have is a needlesdly restricting instructor/tutorial

Answer (score 2):

`enum`s are integer, nothing more nothing less, by defintion.

A possibility way to implement what you might want could be:

```
enum directions {
  DIR_INVALID = -1
  DIR_UP,
  DIR_DOWN,
  DIR_LEFT,
  DIR_RIGHT,
  DIR_MAX
}; 

typedef struct {
  int x;
  int y;
} point;

const point directions[DIR_MAX] = {
  {0, 1},
  {0, -1},
  {-1, 0},
  {1, 0}
};

#define UP directions[DIR_UP]
#define DOWN directions[DIR_DOWN]    
#define LEFT directions[DIR_LEFT]
#define RIGHT directions[DIR_RIGHT]
```